# how to zoom out in Achartengin android studio?

Tags: java, android, graph, achartengine

I am able to zoom in but i need to zoom out please help to resolve
here is my code

```
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0,times.length,0,100});

    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 10, 10, 10, 10 });
    renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);

    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);

    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(8);

    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));
```

by above code i am able to zoom in on touch but i need to zoom out on touch
is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.2.0 the Zoom function (Button) contains three sub-buttons Zoom +, Zoom - and Zoom Limits. It is possible to zoom in or out without any problems.

In build.gradle:
implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')

Downloade here: [achartengine-1.2.0](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine/tree/master/achartengine)